# Should I add sleeps to zeroMQ program initialization to avoid heisenbugs?

Tags: zeromq

I'm working on a zeroMQ proof of concept that involves a master process which publishes control commands and also pushes and pulls data from any number of worker processes.

It seems that on initialization the master and workers (separate processes) *sometimes* get out of sync if I start them up using a shell script.  However, I've never seen this if I start them up in any order manually (in separate console windows).  I'm beginning to consider adding a sleep() after each process binds/connects to the sockets to avoid this apparent heisenbug -- but I'm also wondering if I'm just being stupid.  Any advice?

Here is what the shell script that occasionally fails looks like.  The master talks to the workers using both a PUB and a PUSH and also gets info back using a PULL socket.  I think the heisenbug is caused when a PUB message from the master sometimes is not seen by one of the workers.

```
echo "starting worker A in background"
python pWorkerA.py > /tmp/A.out &
echo "starting worker B in background"
python pWorkerB.py > /tmp/B.out &
echo "starting master"
python abMaster.py
```

I feel like I'm cheating if I use sleep()

Comment: Sadly, I just tried adding a sleep(0.1) at the top of all processes after the sockets are initialized, and that seems to make the problem go away.  I'm not happy about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assume that messages sent on PUB will not arrive on SUB sockets until they have established their connections. Establishing connections takes some finite, if very small, amount of time, so any messages sent in that small window will not arrive on SUBs that haven't yet connected.  An easy way to avoid this is, as you have suggested, adding a sleep to the master after binding.  This is not perfectly reliable, as the workers could technically be super-slow to connect, or be started after the master, and there is no actual signal when they succeed.

A more reliable approach, if you do need to confirm that workers have connected, is to have a handshake mechanism, such that workers send a small "Hi, I'm ready" message (on a different channel) to the master after connecting.  Then, the master only starts publishing messages after it has received the necessary number of handshakes (depending on the appropriate logic for your application).

Comment: Actually, it was the "hi i'm ready" handshake that was failing.  The process works like this:  all processes connect/bind all sockets;  workers send "worker x ready" to master (repeatedly); after master observes all ready signals master publishes "go!".  At that point not all workers see the "go!" signal (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Can you post actual code?  It's possible to write reliable code without sleeps if you do it right.

Comment: I fixed it.  The key was to make sure the workers could hear the publications from the master before they said they were ready to the master.  I still use short sleeps to prevent busy-looping during the handshake phase.  Thanks!